# unity how can ı use ForceMode.Impulse without gravity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a multiplayer fish game. that's why ı unchecked use gravtiy on player's rigidbody to make fish move. I want when player hit a collider the player object bounce back. I wrote this code

```
PlayerRb.AddForce(0, 1f, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

when I use "use gravity" it works but when I don't use "use gravity", player object goes on forever. I want to bounce one time when player hit the ground. Ground has "map" tag. Like this.

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.tag == "taban")
    {
        PlayerRb.AddForce(0, 1f, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);


    }
}
```

But as I said when player hit the "map" player's object goes forever and it doesn't stop. how can ı fix it?
[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB4ps.gif)

Comment: Your question lacks some detail. What is the current behaviour vs what is the expected behaviour? What do you mean "the player objects goes on forever"? That sounds like it's unrelated to gravity, and perhaps you meant friction?

Comment: Describe exactly the behaviour you are seeking. You can add gravity without marking the use gravity tag by doing `PlayerRb.AddForce(Physics.gravity, ForceMode.Acceleration)` in the `FixedUpdate()` method. Maybe you can let this line running for a little period after you hit the collider. It depends on what you want.

Comment: @ErikOverflow ı mean  "the player objects goes on forever" when ı force like this "PlayerRb.AddForce(0, 1f, 0, ForceMode.Impulse); " the object doesn't stop and goes forever ı just want to bounce one time.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean "goes on forever". Can you record your screen and share a gif showing the undesired behaviour.

Comment: @ErikOverflow ı add in the question

Comment: You turned off gravity, so this appears to be functioning correctly. If you want it to only bounce once, then you'll likely need to write some code that counts the number of bounces and zeroes out the velocity after the first bounce.

Comment: I tried rigidbody.velocity = vector3.zero but it didnt work. can you suggest anything? btw thanks for your helps

Comment: Please share your code for what you have tried. It is hard to guide you while blind.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default unity does not have any kind of air resistance when adding force to objects. This means that if you add force to an object and there is no gravity or friction to counteract the force it will keep going forever. To fix this you need to increase the **drag** setting on the player rigidbody. That will make the rigidbody gradually slow down as it travels.

[image: Screenshot of a rigidbody component with "Drag" highlighted]

Here is a demonstration video of how drag will slow down an object.

[image: Demonstration of drag]